# Block until a counter reaches a certain minimum value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a requirement where I need to wait until a counter reaches a certain minimum value.

The scenario is, I have a list of values that gets new values appended every now and then. Other threads can wait until a certain index (or greater index) in this list becomes available. It's possible for the list to contain gaps.

Edit: when a new value becomes available at the requested index (or the nearest greater index if there was a gap), that value should be returned. Each thread waiting for this index is supposed to get the same value. Once this value is processed, the threads may elect to wait for the next index, either getting it immediately if available or blocking until it becomes available.

```
/**
 * Gets the first event available starting from the given
 * index (inclusive). Blocks until an event becomes available.
 *
 * @param fromIndex an index
 * @return an event, never {@code null}
 */
T nextEvent(long fromIndex);
```

Now, I've solved this for now using a `CountDownLatch` that is replaced with a new latch whenever an event arrives. When this occurs, the blocking code checks the new latest event index, and if it is >= `fromIndex` picks it up. Otherwise it picks up the newly replaced `CountDownLatch` and waits on it. Code:

```
private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock readLock = lock.readLock();
private final Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();

private CountDownLatch eventAvailableLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
private long latestIndex;

@Override
public T nextEvent(long fromIndex) {
  for(;;) {
    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    readLock.lock();

    try {
      if(fromIndex > latestIndex) {
        latch = this.eventAvailableLatch;
      }
    }
    finally {
      readLock.unlock();
    }

    if(latch == null) {
      break;  // new event with index >= fromIndex is available!
    }

    try {
      latch.await();  // wait for new event to become available (many threads could be here)
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }

  // return the event
}
```

The code that adds a new event is like this:

```
public long append(T event) {
  writeLock.lock();

  try {
    this.latestIndex = storeEvent(event);  // may fail, and next call could skip an index creating a gap

    eventAvailableLatch.countDown();
    eventAvailableLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    return latestIndex;
  }
  finally {
    writeLock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Now, I'm under the impression that this is rather cumbersome, and perhaps even a bit wasteful creating a new `CountDownLatch` every time an event comes in. Also the need for the using both a latch and a read lock to get this working safely seems over the top.

I've considered looking at `Condition`s, but they seem to require every thread that may be waiting on the `eventAvailable` condition to acquire the write lock, which means only one thread can wake up at a time when the condition is signalled. With the latch at least it seems all threads can be woken up simultaneously.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This solution looks as if it does not exactly do what is described if `fromIndex>latestIndex+1`. Also it is not clear whether many threads may pick up the same event or whether `fromIndex` means: get the first event not handled by another thread with an index `>=fromIndex`.

Comment: Clarification: All threads should pick up all events, they're independent processors of the same events.

Comment: @Harald if I want the next event (100) and the latestIndex is 100, then it can pick it up (`100 > 100 == false`).  If I want 101, and latest is 100, then it should wait (`101 > 100 == true`).  I think the condition is correct?

Comment: If you want 700 and the latest is 100, your CountDownlatch lets you pick up event 101 I think, because it is initialized with just 1.

Comment: @Harald that's exactly was is intended, then it picks up 102, 103, etc.  It's supposed to get all events that were recorded from a certain point.  That point can be 0 (in which case it gets everything) or a million (and it gets only everything from there and up) or the current latest index, in which case it gets nothing until something new arrives.

Comment: @Harald disgregard my previous comment (I can't edit it anymore). It will not pick up 101 when you want 700.  Instead, it will unblock, check the condition again (and see that 700 > 101 is still `true`, and it will block again (on the replaced `CountDownLatch`, not the old one).  It will unblock 599 more times before it reaches 700... which is maybe why I think this code could be improved perhaps?

Comment: You could use `CompletableFuture`s to implement `nextEvent` instead of `CountDownLatch`. One way would be to implement a specialized `CompletableFuture` that keeps track of `fromIndex`. Each time `append` is called, it iterates over all pending futures completing those with a matching `fromIndex`.

Comment: @john16384 Ooompf, sorry, you are right, I falsely saw the `// return event` inside the loop.